# Как спарсить цену игры в Steam?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть скрипт на Python, который парсит эту страницу: https://store.steampowered.com/app/268540/The_Whispered_World_Special_Edition/

Скрипт выводит тег html, в нём текст: 299 руб. Подскажите, как можно на выводе иметь тег не только со словом 229 руб., а вот так: Цена в Steam: 299 руб.

И так с любой игрой, не только с этой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [replace_with](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with).

```
def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    price = soup.find('div', class_='discount_original_price')
    if price is None:
        price = soup.find('div', class_='game_purchase_price price')
    price.string.replace_with('Цена в Steam: ' + price.string)
    print(price)
```